# How to get data between headers?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt. I want below input to be converted into output shown below:

Input:

```
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
    <THE-VALUE>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498885">Main Description</h1>
            Line1 The main description text goes here.
            <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
            &lt;p&gt;Line3 The main description text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;
            <p><img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"/></p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498886">Key Consideration</h1>
            <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498887">Skills</h1>
            <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498888">Synonyms</h1>
            &lt;p&gt;The Synonyms text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;
        </div>
    </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Output should be:

```
<MainDescription>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line3 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p><img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"/></p>
    ]]>
</MainDescription>
<KeyConsiderations>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
    ]]>
</KeyConsiderations>
<Skills>
    <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
</Skills>
<Synonyms>
    <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
</Synonyms>
```

I want the data between `<h1>` and it can contain any html tag that should be generated in output. I tried the code at: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/2. But it gives the data only if data is included under html tags. Please provide pointers on how to achieve required output.

XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml exsl"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
    cdata-section-elements="MainDescription KeyConsideration"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="h1-group" match="xhtml:div/*[not(self::xhtml:h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[xhtml:h1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:variable name="rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped)/node()" mode="xml-to-string"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting output as:

```
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
  <THE-VALUE>
    <MainDescription><![CDATA[<p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p><p><img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/></p>]]></MainDescription>
    <KeyConsideration><![CDATA[<p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p><p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>]]></KeyConsideration>
    <Skills>&lt;p&gt;Line1 The Skills text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Line2 The Skills text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Line3 The Skills text goes here.&lt;/p&gt;</Skills>
    <Synonyms />
  </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have and the current result you get in the question as well and then explain in what way the result does not match the expectation? Is the example input in the sample you linked to intentionally different to the one you have shown in the question?

Comment: I tried the code in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/2 and applied it to input mentioned in this post. This code is working correctly if the text is included in html tags. But if text is not in html tags, I don't get anything.

Comment: Well, the code you linked to matches element nodes with `*`, if you have other nodes as well to be wrapped by the heading then see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/41. But your input/output transformation seems to have several requirements, it is not clear when you want a CDATA and it is not clear where the `p` element in the wanted output `<p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>` comes from, it seems you have various requirements best asked separately in separate questions.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the code to match on `node()` instead of `*` for elements you get the text nodes included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml exsl"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
    cdata-section-elements="MainDescription KeyConsideration"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="h1-group" match="xhtml:div/node()[not(self::xhtml:h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[xhtml:h1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1[. = 'Main Description' or . = 'Key Consideration']">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:variable name="rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped)/node()" mode="xml-to-string"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:variable name="rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped)/node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/41

It is not clear when/where you want to wrap plain text like `Line1 The main description text goes here.` into a `p` element.

For the CDATA section use of `disable-output-escaping` I think you need to override the template for `text()` nodes of the imported `xml-to-string` stylesheet:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="xml-to-string">
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/42

I haven't tested whether that breaks anything.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The code works as expected for non-cdata section. The same output is expected for cdata-section as well. For eg. &lt;p&gt;Line3 The main description text goes here.&lt;/p&gt; in Cdata-section should be transformed to <p>Line3 The main description text goes here.</p>

Comment: Thanks Martin,this is what I wanted.

Comment: One more query, the solution works with https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/, but not in eclipse java transformer with xalan_2.7.1. If I replace * with node(), I don't get anything in tags like <MainDescription>, <KeyConsiderations> or <Skills>. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @VishalSharnagat, no idea, I don't use Xalan as in the Java world Saxon easily gives you XSLT 2 or 3. If you need help with that particular problem I think your best bet is to ask a new, separate question with minimal details of XML, XSLT, Java code, to allow others to easily reproduce the problem. Then hopefully someone can tell how to resolve it.